# Transforming small WAV files in a single value of frequency (PYTHON)

Tags: python, windows, average, wav, frequency

I'm  in a need for a program that transforms tones recorded by the microphone into keybord presses. Example: if somebody sings at a frequency between 400hz and 600hz at the microphone and the average tone is 550hz, then i store the average frequency in the var 'tom', and the key "G" of my keyboard is pressed.
Even tho i'm newbye at programming, i searched and figured out a way to do so,
by using Audiopy at python language, by recording small WAV files, i could then read those and get a number as an average frequency, and with this number and some ifs and elifs, press keys (not that hard to find a code to press keys), in an enormous WHILE that repeats the process while the program runs, and so i would have the process of talking, reading the small files the talk would produce, and then transforming into key presses, according to the tone.

The main problem is that I have no idea on how to transform the WAV files i've been recording on a single average number of frequency. Can somebody help me with this? Or with the big picture? Cuz i know this method is not a really good one. Thanks! I was using this code to record, that I found on the Audiopy website:

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import numpy as np
import pyaudio

CHUNK = 2048
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 1
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output1.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("* done chunk")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

To press the keys, this other code:

```
import win32com.client
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    if tom >= 400 and tom<=500:
    shell.SendKeys("G")
```

PS.: I'm using Windows

Comment: You don't need to put `<code>` tags around your code. Just indent it four spaces. You can do that by selecting your code and pressing the button labelled `{}` in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Fourier transform to convert sound into frequencies.
More specifically, use the one-dimensional discrete Fourier Transform provided by [`numpy.fft.rfft`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html).

An example to read a single second from a stereo WAV file and extract the frequencies.

```
import wave
import numpy as np

with wave.open('input.wav', 'r') as wr:
    sz = wr.getframerate()  # Read and process 1 second.
    da = np.fromstring(wr.readframes(sz), dtype=np.int16)
    left, right = da[0::2], da[1::2]  # separate into left and right channel
    lf, rf = np.absolute(np.fft.rfft(left)), np.absolute(np.fft.rfft(right))
```

The `lf` and `rf` are numpy arrays containing the intensity of each frequency. Using [`numpy.argmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) you can get the index (frequency) with the highest strength.

But try it and graph the result using e.g. `matplotlib`. You'll see that there are probably multiple peaks in the data. For example you might find a peak at 50 Hz or 60 Hz. This is most probably interference from mains electricity and should be ignored by zero-ing out the data.
Example for 60 Hz:

```
lf[55:65], rf[55:65] = 0, 0
```

Below is an example plot made with matplotlib from a one-second sound clip. The top graph shows the samples from the WAV file while the bottom one shows the same data converted to frequencies. This is a graph of a person speaking, so there are many peaks. The highest is around 200 Hz.

[image: example plot]